# Array bidimensional con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde debo mostar en una tabla Los nombres de los alumnos, asignaturas y sus notas, no se si esto que he hecho está bien. Lo que intento hacer es un array donde esten los nombres de los alumnos y otro array bidimensional asociativo, donde estén las notas y asignaturas, queriendo hacer un map para que la clave sea alumuno y el valor asignaturas, y printarlo en una tabla

pero no me sale absolutamente nada cuando ejecuto el programa, ni fallos en consola ni nada. S eque estoy haciendo el for mal, pero no se como hacerlo para que recoja todo.

```js
    var map = new Map();
    var alumnos = ["Juan", "Pepe", "Alba", "Maria", "Alvaro", "Roberto", "Laura", "Daniel", "Cristina", "David"];
    var asignaturas = new Array();
    asignaturas[0] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[1] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[2] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[3] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[4] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[5] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[6] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[7] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[8] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[9] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    
    map.set(alumnos, asignaturas);
    document.write("<table bordes=1>");
    for (i = 0; i < map; i++) {
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td>i</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez esto es lo que buscas:

```js
var alumnos = ["Juan", "Pepe", "Alba", "Maria", "Alvaro", "Roberto", "Laura", "Daniel", "Cristina", "David"];
    var asignaturas = new Array();
    asignaturas[0] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[1] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[2] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[3] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[4] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[5] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[6] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[7] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[8] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    asignaturas[9] = new Array({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
    
    console.log(asignaturas[0][0])
    
    function relate() {
      var mapped = [];
      for (var i=0;i<alumnos.length;i++) {
        var currentUser = alumnos[i];
        var currentAsign = asignaturas[i];
        mapped.push({[currentUser]:currentAsign})
      }
      return mapped
    }
    
    console.log(relate())
```

Ya después puedes implementar el array como lo necesites.

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = new Map();
var alumnos = ["Juan", "Pepe", "Alba", "Maria", "Alvaro", "Roberto", "Laura", "Daniel", "Cristina", "David"];
var asignaturas = [];
asignaturas[0] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[1] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[2] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[3] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[4] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[5] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[6] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[7] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[8] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
asignaturas[9] = new Object({ "Lenguaje": "4", "Matematicas": "7", "Musica": "8", "Ingles": "9", "Fisica": "5" });
//Debes asignar a cada alumno un objeto que definan sus calificaciones
for(var i = 0; i < alumnos.length;i++){
  map.set(alumnos[i], asignaturas[i]);
}

document.write("<table bordes=1>");
//te recomiendo iterar de esta manera y así obtener los valores de cada objeto
for(var [key,value] of map){
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>"+key+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>Lenguaje: "+value.Lenguaje+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>Matematicas: "+value.Matematicas+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>Musica: "+value.Musica+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>Ingles: "+value.Ingles+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>Fisica: "+value.Fisica+"</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene muchos problemas, te mostrare cada uno de ellos.

Primero, en `map.set(alumnos, asignaturas)` estas poniendo en el objeto map un solo array con todos los objetos dentro. Tienes que poner todo los objetos en el objeto map. De esta manera

```
var map = new Map()
map.set("Juan", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("Pepe", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("Alba", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("Maria", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("Alvaro", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("Roberto", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("Laura", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("Daniel", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("Cristina", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
map.set("David", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 })
```

Lo siguiente, tu quieres imprimir la información con `document.write()`, lo que no te lo recomiendo. Yo diría que crees una función para crear elementos DOM y poner la información ahí. Le pasas por parámetro el tipo de etiqueta y el elemento padre para que se situé.

```
function crearElemento(etiqueta, padre) {
    const $elemento = document.createElement(etiqueta)
    padre.appendChild($elemento)
    return $elemento
}
```

Otra es que, el bucle for, esta  mal armado. Tienes que sacar el length con el método size. También, con `map.get(i)` obtenemos cada registro del map. Y le pasamos el registro en el elemento DOM con `$box.textContent = map.get(i)`

```
for (var i = 0; i < map.size; i++) {
    const $box = crearElemento('span', $tabla)
    $box.textContent = map.get(i)
}
```

Tu querías imprimir los registros en una tabla. Quite la etiqueta tabla y la remplace con un div, ya que le faltaba mucha estructura. Cada registro es una etiqueta span.

En general, quedaría este código

```
var map = new Map();
map.set("Juan", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("Pepe", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("Alba", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("Maria", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("Alvaro", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("Roberto", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("Laura", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("Daniel", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("Cristina", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });
map.set("David", { Lenguaje: 4, Matematicas: 7, Musica: 8, Ingles: 9, Fisica: 5 });

const $tabla = crearElemento('div', document.body);
    for (var i = 0; i < map.size; i++) {
    const $box = crearElemento('span', $tabla);
    $box.textContent = map.get(i);
}

function crearElemento(etiqueta, padre) {
    const $elemento = document.createElement(etiqueta);
    padre.appendChild($elemento);
    return $elemento;
}
```